# Prove that $X^{\phi{(n)}}-[1]$ has exactly $\phi{(n)}$ roots in $\mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $X^{\phi{(n)}}-[1]$ has exactly $\phi{(n)}$ roots in $\mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z}$, and they are the elements of $(\mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z})^\times$.

I know that $(\mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z})^\times =\{ [a] \in \mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z} :  \gcd(a,n)=1 \}$, and ...

For any $[a] \in (\mathbf{Z} / n \mathbf{Z})^\times$, then $[a]^{\phi{(n)}}=[1]$.

Can I use any of these two facts to prove this statement.

Comment: The result you are asked to prove is basically a restatement of Euler's Theorem. If you have had Euler's Theorem already in the course, then the proof will be  quick.

Comment: This is [proposition 3.3.2 in Ireland & Rosen](http://books.google.com/books?id=jhAXHuP2y04C&lpg=PA73&ots=ihpTBxSIhv&dq=ireland%20and%20rosen%20%22proposition%203.3.2%22&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that $[a]^{\phi(n)} = [1]$ or equivalently that $[a]$ is a root of $X^{\phi(n)} - [1]$ for any $[a] = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. You probably also know that a polynomial of degree $k$ can have at most $k$ distinct roots? If so we are done. We have $X^{\phi(n)} - [1]$ a polynomial of degree $\phi(n)$ and we have found $\phi(n)$ roots. Thus me have all the roots and they are exactly what we are looking for.

CORRECTION: The above works in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ a prime, and hence we are in a field. Otherwise we need a different argument. See AWertheim's comment below.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that the second line of reasoning is right. It is true that a polynomial of degree $k$ can have at most $k$ distinct roots in a FIELD. In a ring, a polynomial of degree $k$ can have more than $k$ roots (consider the roots of $x^{2}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$). I believe the reason we are done is that roots of this polynomial can only come from $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, because if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^{\phi(n)} - [1]$, then $\alpha^{\phi(n)} = 1$, hence $\alpha$ is invertible.

Comment: Good point. I my head I was thinking the $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ case for prime $p$, but we are working over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for any $n$.